# Rotation of a spin-1/2 system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, rotation, spinors

The Hamiltonian of a spin 1/2 system in a magnetic field $\mathbf{B} = B \hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is \begin{equation}\hat{H} = - \frac{e}{mc} \hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}} \cdot \mathbf{B} \end{equation}

where $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is an arbitrary vector and $\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}$ the vector of Pauli matrices, i.e.  $\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}} = (\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$.

Now the problem is to find the eigenspinors of the Hamiltonian.

My first idea (which works fine) was to first consider the system with $\hat{\mathbf{n}} = (0,0,1)$:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} = \sigma_3
\end{equation}

In this case the eigenspinors are known and by rotating the system it is possible to find the eigenspinors for the system with arbitrary $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$.

More specifically, one eigenspinor (before rotation) is $\chi_+ = (1,0)$ and applying the rotation in SU(2):
\begin{equation}
e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \sigma_z \varphi} e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \sigma_y \theta}\chi_+ = \begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\varphi/2} \cos(\theta/2) \\ e^{i\varphi/2} \sin(\theta/2)\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
which is (up to a phase factor) the result from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenspinor)

Another way is to start with an arbitrary magnetic field and then compute the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian. That is, one rotates the vector $\hat{\mathbf{n}} = (0,0,1)$ such that afterwards $\hat{\mathbf{n}} = (\cos \varphi \sin \theta, \sin \varphi \sin \theta,\cos \theta)$. Doing this one finds the same eigenspinors.

So I see that the results are the same, however, I don't really understand how the 3-dimensional rotation (of the space) is related to the 2-dimensional one (of the spinor). 
I know that SU(2) is a double cover of SO(3) but I don't see how one would formally relate the two in the above example. 
I guess that the answer is somehow related to the homomorphism between the groups (or their Lie algebra) but I confused myself so much that I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see how one would formally relate the two in the above example

Let 
$$
\hat{\sigma}\cdot{\underline{n}}= n^1\hat{\sigma}_1  + n^2\hat{\sigma}_2+n^3\hat{\sigma}_3 = \hat{S}(\theta,\phi)\hat{\sigma}_3
$$
namely any combination of Pauli matrices can always be written as the product of one other Pauli matrix times another object in $SU(2)$. The matrix $\hat{S}(\theta,\phi)$ is, in the case at hand, the element
$$
\hat{S}(\theta, \phi) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-i\phi/2}\cos(\theta/2)\quad e^{-i\phi/2}\sin(\theta/2)\\
e^{i\phi/2}\sin(\theta/2)\quad e^{i\phi/2}\cos(\theta/2)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now let us associate two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the above equation, one to the left hand side and one to the right hand side, namely
$$
(n^1, n^2, n^3)\mapsto(0,0,n'^3)
$$
as the right hand side only possesses the $\sigma_3$. Let $\hat{R}(\theta, \phi)$ the transformation matrix such that
$$
\hat{R}(\theta, \phi)\,(n^1, n^2, n^3) = (0,0,n'^3).
$$
As such we have now two objects at our disposal:
$$
\hat{S}(\theta, \phi)\in SU(2),\qquad \hat{R}(\theta,\phi)\in SO(3);
$$
the map $\rho\colon S\mapsto R$ for each pair $(\theta, \phi)$ is the desired double covering map (one can show that both $S$ and $-S$ correspond to the same $R$).

Because of the above argument multiplying the $\sigma$ by $\hat{S}$ is equivalent to multiplying $\underline{n}$ by $\hat{R}$, that is why the eigenvalues are the same no matter whichever multiplication you perform first.

Comment: Shouldn't $\hat{S}(\theta, \phi)$ be a 2x2-matrix? So maybe something like $\begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\varphi/2} \cos(\theta/2) & -e^{-i\varphi/2} \sin(\theta/2)\\ e^{i\varphi/2} \sin(\theta/2) & e^{i\varphi/2} \cos(\theta/2)\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Virft Oh yes, of course, I forgot to add the right hand side, thanks :p!